# Linking a program with both OpenBLAS and IntelMKL

Tags: dynamic-linking, intel-mkl, openblas

Since Intel MKL's blas library and OpenBLAS's library have the same interface, I find that the order in which I link my program to these libraries will affect whether a function in MKL will be called or a function in OpenBLAS will be called.

Actually I want to selectively call either MKL's matrix multiplication or OpenBLAS's matrix multiplication.

How can I do that?